# What does !cp:$ do?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, file-copy

I saw this command in the documentation of one of the programs in my work:

```
cp company-sso /usr/local/bin/company-sso ; sudo chmod +x !cp:$
```

I'm aware that `:` will stop the next command from being executed, it'll only be evaluated, but how does this work with `$`? I've only seen `$` used before a variable name, like `$USER` or `$HOME` but never alone. Also, how does `!cp` work? It won't execute `cp`? What's the purpose of this? Does this whole line make any sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "*: will stop the next command from being executed, it'll only be evaluated*"? I don't know of any such feature. Could you be thinking of the shell builtin `:`, the "null command"? That is just a shortcut for doing nothing and returning true (see `help :`).

Comment: That's not the dollar sign being "alone" there

Comment: `install --mode +x company-sso /usr/local/bin/company-sso` would probably be more appropriate. `install` isn't a standard command, but then again, history expansion is not a standard shell feature, either.

Comment: Someone is being clever at the expense of clarity. Don't do this.

Answer (score 26):

This is [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html), introduced by `!`; the `$` must be intepreted in that context. `!cp:$` has two parts, separated by `:`. `!cp` is the event designator, it means “find the most recent command starting with `cp`”. `$` is a word designator, it means “take the last word (argument) in the selected command”.

So, assuming the last command in the history (of previously-run commands) is also `cp company-sso /usr/local/bin/company-sso`, `!cp:$` is replaced with `/usr/local/bin/company-sso`, and the command run is `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/company-sso`.

As [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658699/what-does-cp-do/658700?noredirect=1#comment1240238_658700) by [jschimpf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/482029/jschimpf), history expansion doesn’t consider the current command line when searching for previous commands matching a string, so if both commands in the question are entered in the same line, the `cp` before `;` isn’t a candidate. This means that the command given in your question would only really be useful as two separate lines:

```
cp company-sso /usr/local/bin/company-sso
sudo chmod +x !cp:$
```

“`:` will stop the next command from being executed, it'll only be evaluated”, but only when `:` is used as a command; it doesn’t apply in other cases where `:` is present in a command line. `:` as a command is a [shell special built-in](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), which always succeeds, ignoring its arguments; but any expansion in the arguments is indeed performed, and when the rules for special built-ins are followed, variable assignments are also preserved. (Bash doesn’t apply this rule by default.)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The "most recent command starting with cp" is not the one on the left hand side of the semicolon, but the most recent earlier command line starting with cp. For instance `true a` followed by `true b ; echo !tr:$` will print a not b.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @jschimpf, I’ve made the assumptions explicit.

Comment: You could also use `cp company-sso /usr/local/bin/company-sso ; sudo chmod +x !#:2`; `!#` refers to the entire command line so far, but `$` would refer to `+x` (the last argument prior to the `!#`, so you'll have to count arguments yourself to select the correct target.

Comment: If you're doing the second command immediately after, it's simpler to just write `!$`. I used that history shortcut all the time.